# Unable to save video captured via webcam in Aura Component

Tags: apex, aura, blob, video

I have an Aura component that captures video via webcam and displays it to the user while also giving them the option to save it.

The "playback" feature works as expected using the following JS -

```
const blob = new Blob(dataChunks, { type : 'video\/mp4' });
var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
const videoURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

And then setting that URL as the src in a `<video>` tag.

The problem I'm having is when I try and save the video using my Apex controller.  I've tried the following approaches -

- Pass the data as a Blob data type from JS controller to Apex.  The Class and method are invoked, but nothing is executed (not even a system debug on the first line). No exceptions are thrown.
- Used an XMLHttpRequest to convert the Blob to a String in the Javascript controller and passed it to the Apex Method.  The Apex Method is set up to receive a Blob param.  It accepts the param, and creates a ContentVersion record that is unplayable (both in the browser and when downloaded). I've tried this with the mp4 blob and by creating a second "plain text" blob.
- Tried the previous method but configured Apex to receive a String parameter instead of a Blob.  Converting the string to a Blob using `Blob.valueOf()` creates an unplayable mp4 file, while trying to decode EncodingUtil methods (both `urlDecode()` and `base64Decode()` return the following error -

[image: dev console error]

- I've tried using the `btoa()` method to encode in Base64 and send to Apex.  No matter what blob I pass in (mp4 or plain text version), this method always returns `W29iamVjdCBCbG9iXQ==` which is the literal string `'[object Blob]'` encoded in Base64.
- Passing in the video src URL to the Apex method.  The URL makes it into the Apex method but I haven't been able to use this URL to appropriately fill in the "VersionData" (Blob data type) field for the ContentVersion record. The URL is as follows -

`blob:https://sleeping-panther-44538.lightning.force.com/5ceddd5d-095a-4598-8251-56fd85bcb5d2`

I'm coming up on about 18 hours trying to solve this issue and am getting no where.  Any help here would be greatly appreciated.